# SQL query to get average sum of other rows and store in current rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, average, aggregate-functions

I have table like this, and I want to query to store the average of others row points.

```
USER_ID        POINTS       
------------- --------
 a14e43e4f851  134       
 1e86e5adedbf  40     
 3c66730edf69  149  
 32e24082f97b  67   
 b33e3100a7be  124  
 274ee414ad8f  85   
 bdeef25fc797  172
```

For example - for `user_id` = `a14e43e4f851`, the average sum of points should be
`avg(40+149+67+124+85+172)` .
PS - not taken the points (134) in calculation for user `a14e43e4f851`.

Output should look like this --

```
 USER_ID       POINTS   AVG     
-------------  ------- ------
 a14e43e4f851   134     106 which is avg(40+149+67+124+85+172)  
 1e86e5adedbf   40      avg(134+149+67+124+85+172)
 3c66730edf69   149     avg(134+40+67+124+85+172)
 32e24082f97b   67      avg(134+40+149+124+85+172)
 b33e3100a7be   124     ...
 274ee414ad8f   85      ...
 bdeef25fc797   172     ...
```

Comment: What outcome you are expecting if there is only one record in your table?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
    (select avg(t1.points) from mytable t1 where t1.user_id <> t.user_id) as average
from mytable t
```

An alternative uses window functions:

```
select t.*,
    (sum(points) over() - points) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0) as average
from mytable t
```

Note: `avg` obviously conflicts with a language keyword, I use `average` instead.

If you wanted an `update` statement:

```
update mytable t
set t.average = (
    select avg(t1.points) from mytable t1 where t1.user_id <> t.user_id
)
```

However, I would not recommend actually storing this value; this is *derived information*, that can easily be computed on the fly whenever needed, using the first statement. If you are going to run the query often, you could create a view:

```
create view myview as
select t.*,
    (sum(points) over() - points) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0) as average
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming user_id is the PK.

```
WITH q AS (SELECT sum(points) AS s, count(*) AS n FROM mytable)
UPDATE table SET average = (q.s-points)/(q.n-1);
```

The idea is that

- average of all other user's score is sum(score)/count(*)
- sum of all user scores except this one is equal to sum of all scores minus this user's score
- average of all other users' score except this one is (sum(score)-score_for_this_user)/(count(*)-1)

Nice thing is it only has to calculate the sum() and count() once.

To handle the case where there is only one row in the table:

```
WITH q AS (SELECT sum(points) AS s, NULLIF(count(*),0) AS n FROM mytable)
UPDATE table SET average = (q.s-points)/(q.n-1);
```

This makes the count NULL instead of 0, so the average updated should be NULL too.

Comment: You should handle the situation where there is only one record in the table.